# Error Parsing Data Org.Json.JSONException: End Of Input At Charac

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to connect to my database on localhost through my android app on eclipse. (I am very new to this all). I have no errors in my code but when I run the app and enter my details and hit the "save" `Button` the app stops responding and gives the below error

```
Error Parsing Data Org.Json.JSONException: End Of Input At Charac
```

I am not sure if the error issue is with my Json array or my actual php file. I have seen numerous questions similar to this online but have still not found a fix, could anyone suggest anything for me to try?

**my class is:**

```
package com.example.independentretailers;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.independentretailers.R;
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class retailersignup extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

EditText etRetailName, etTypeofBusiness, etLocation, etGPS, etPhoneNumber,    etEmail, etPassword;
Button bSave;

private static String url_create_reatiler = "http://10.0.2.2/tutorial2.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

//  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setup strict mode policy 
 //     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
//      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.retailersignup);
    //for Retail name
    etRetailName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //for type of business 
    etTypeofBusiness = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    //for Location
    etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    //for GPS
    etGPS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); 
    //for Phone Number
    etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    //for email
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    //for password
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    //setting up ID for the button 
    bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //setting up onclick listener 
    bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        InputStream is = null;
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View arg0){
                 new CreateNewRetailer().execute();
        }
    });
  }

class CreateNewRetailer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{ 

protected String doInBackground(String...args){
            //storing values inside edit texts inside strings 
            String RetailName = etRetailName.getText().toString();
            String TypeofBusiness = etTypeofBusiness.getText().toString(); 
            String Location = etLocation.getText().toString();
            String GPS = etGPS.getText().toString();
            String PhoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString(); 
            String Email = etEmail.getText().toString(); 
            String Password = etPassword.getText().toString(); 

            //setting name pair values 
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new     ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //adding string values inside the name value pairs 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Retail Name",    RetailName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type of Business",   TypeofBusiness));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Location", Location));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GPS", GPS));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone Number", PhoneNumber));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", Password));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest     (url_create_reatiler, "POST", nameValuePairs);
            //setting up the connection inside the try catch 

            try{ 
                //setting up the default client
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

 return null;
}

protected void onPostExcute(String file_url){
pDialog.dismiss();

}
}
}
```

My JsonParser class is: 
    package com.example.independentretailers;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

 }
}

<?php 

$response = array();

$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
mysql_select_db("independentretailers",$con); 

if (isset($_POST['Retail Name']) && isset($_POST['Type of Business']) &&   isset($_POST['Location'])&& isset($_POST['GPS'])&& isset($_POST['Phone    Number'])&& isset($_POST['Email'])&& isset($_POST['Password'])) {


$RetailName = $_POST['Retail Name']; 
$TypeofBusiness = $_POST['Type of Business'];
$Location = $_POST['Location'];
$GPS = $_POST['GPS'];
$PhoneNumber = $_POST['Phone Number'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO retailer(Retail Name, Type of Business,    Location, GPS, Phone Number, Email, Password)    VALUES('$RetailName','$TypeofBusiness','$Location','$GPS','$PhoneNumber','$Email    ','$Password')");
```

// check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Retailer successfully created.";

```
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**My full logcat error is:**

```
04-17 15:45:54.393: D/dalvikvm(555): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-17 15:45:55.263: I/dalvikvm(555): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-17 15:45:55.393: I/dalvikvm(555): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-17 15:45:55.775: I/dalvikvm(555): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-17 15:45:55.854: I/dalvikvm(555): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-17 15:45:56.264: I/dalvikvm(555): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-17 15:45:56.354: I/dalvikvm(555): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-17 15:45:56.635: D/gralloc_goldfish(555): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-17 15:45:56.763: I/dalvikvm(555): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-17 15:45:56.863: I/dalvikvm(555): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-17 15:47:12.763: I/dalvikvm(555): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-17 15:47:12.783: I/dalvikvm(555): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-17 15:47:15.883: D/dalvikvm(555): GC_CONCURRENT freed 169K, 5% free 6749K/7047K, paused 8ms+6ms
04-17 15:47:32.033: D/dalvikvm(555): GC_CONCURRENT freed 386K, 8% free 6785K/7303K, paused 5ms+26ms
04-17 15:47:37.123: E/JSON Parser(555): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-17 15:47:37.123: W/dalvikvm(555): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at com.example.independentretailers.retailersignup$CreateNewRetailer.doInBackground(retailersignup.java:97)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at com.example.independentretailers.retailersignup$CreateNewRetailer.doInBackground(retailersignup.java:1)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-17 15:47:37.166: E/AndroidRuntime(555):  ... 5 more
04-17 15:47:40.524: I/dalvikvm(579): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-17 15:47:40.582: I/dalvikvm(579): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-17 15:47:40.753: D/gralloc_goldfish(579): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error parsing your JSON. I recommend logging your JSON response, maybe like that:

```
// try parse the string to a JSON object
try {
    Log.d("My JSON", json);
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
```

From there you can see if the problem is in your PHP or in your app.

Comment: I know, this is not the solution. But you should run in again and check your logs and see what is your JSON response. If possible post it here.

Comment: I don't think it is hitting the JSON at all because it can't access the try catch and my log messages aren't changing from the first time?

Comment: Your exception is "Error parsing data" and not "Error converting result", which means it got the response but it's throwing an exception when it is parsing your data. Again, my answer is not to solve your problem, but to know what you are receiving to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: ok i understand.. this may seem really silly but where do I find my log? I can't seem to find it only logcat

Comment: Inside your logcat you see your logs. Look for the one you just added, or use Ctrl + F and look for "My JSON".

Comment: I still just get the same logcat as before and when I use Ctrl +F and look for MY JSON it says string not found?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong order. You should log your JSON before trying to parse it. See my edited answer.

Comment: I changed my answer to your edited one but my logcat still isn't changing or saying anything about JSON?

Comment: Did you try ctrl F again?

Comment: Yeah it just keeps saying string not found

Comment: Sorry then, don't know how to help anymore

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps figure the issue out but I now get the error - "Error converting result.java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: You gotta know where this error is coming from, so you know what object you're trying to access is null. Click on the exception, it should take you to the line where it was thrown

Comment: It doesn't do anything when I click on the exception

Comment: when i test my php file in the browser it shows the last else statement - {"success":0,"message":"required field(s) is missing"}